# Getting deformation object in spark ar environment

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to get deformation object to change it properties by JS, but I cannot even get it by any Spark module.

Spark AR have sample project with face distortion deformation. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/tutorials-and-samples/samples/face-distortion/
You can even see in tutorial, that there is some morph object attached, which called faceDistortionPack. This object is located in assets, and I tried to get it by different ways in script, but couldn't make it. I want to write some js logic to manipulate deformations.

```js
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

const faceMesh = Scene.root.find('facemesh_distortion');

Diagnostics.log(faceMesh); // FaceMesh: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/scenemodule.facemesh
Diagnostics.log(faceMesh.deformation); // null
Diagnostics.log(faceMesh.find('faceDistortionPack')); // Exception...
// ....
```

I want to get 'faceDistortionPack' object to access it properties, like 'nose_z', so I can change them by JS.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a pretty old question I thought I'd answer anyway if anyone struggles with this and comes across this thread.

First of all: There's an amazing collection of helpful tips, tutorials, snippets etc. called [Spark AR Community](https://github.com/Spark-AR-Community). There you can find a [GitBook](https://sparkar-community.gitbook.io/docs/) with an alternative, better indexed and better working version of the official script object reference. I recommend using it if you're lost in the official reference or it's not working which happens quite often. There you can see, that the BlendShapesMesh, mentioned in the previous answer is [deprecated as of Spark AR v85+](https://sparkar-community.gitbook.io/docs/asynchronous-api-changes-v85), so that won't help anyone. ()

So, what you are trying to achieve, if I understand it correctly, is to access the faceMesh's Blendshapes and change their value through script. What you need to do is this:

1. Follow the instructions in this Tutorial: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/tutorials/face-distortion-retouching/
2. After you applied the Blendshapes, mess around a bit with adjusting the Blendshapes, so you understand what's happening.
3. Add a script to your assets. You're gonna want to access the faceMesh-Object's Blendshapes' weight Property through script. That can be done by using the getBlendshapes()-Method of the [Mesh-Class](https://sparkar-community.gitbook.io/docs/scenemodule/mesh#methods).
   Here's a code example:

```
//Require Modules
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');
const Reactive = require('Reactive');

//Enable async/await [part 1]
(async function () {

  //Load Assets as Promise

const loadAssets = await Promise.all(
  [
      Scene.root.findFirst("faceMesh0"),  //Put name of your facemesh here, default is faceMesh0
  ]
).then(function(assets){
    const faceMesh = assets[0]; //Assign the facemesh from the assets-Array of the promise to a variable you can work with better
    const faceMeshShapes = faceMesh.getBlendShapes(); //Access all Blendshapes of the faceMesh-Object and store them in an Array
```

What you have now is a variable called faceMeshShapes, that's an object with an array of Blenshapes in it. You can console log it with `Diagnostics.log(faceMeshShapes)` and see that there's an array called "_value" in it, that's filled with all Blendshapes as objects, that have a [weight-Property](https://sparkar-community.gitbook.io/docs/scenemodule/blendshape), which specifies the weight of the Blendshape with a [scalarValue](https://sparkar-community.gitbook.io/docs/reactivemodule/scalarvalue). You can consolelog this Value by converting it with the pinLastValue()-Method of the scalarValue-Class and you can assign different values by binding it to a custom value, that you convert to a scalarValue by using the val()-Method from the Reactive-Module.
Here's an example:

```
Diagnostics.log(faceMeshShapes._value[0].weight.pinLastValue()); //console log the Value of the weight property's scalarValue of the Blendshape that's stored at the index 0 of the _value-Array
faceMeshShapes._value[0].weight = Reactive.val(0.5) //set the weight to 0.5
Diagnostics.log(faceMeshShapes._value[0].weight.pinLastValue()); //console log the changed value of the weight property
```

So basically, that's how you can access every Blendshape's weight. The index should be according to the order in which they are listed in spar AR studio, beginning with 0 for the first BlendShape. Now you can do lots of things with this value, like binding it to an animation that animates it from 0-1 or to the mouth-openess using the face-tracking module and so on.

Last but not least, don't forget any semicolons and close all brackets.

```
  });

})(); // Enable async/await [part 2]
```

P.S.: It can really help sometimes to understand what's happening and how to access stuff, by console logging a list of all properties of an object. Especially since the spark AR documentation is pretty weak on that part (and pretty weak in general). You can use the following function from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#enumerate_the_properties_of_an_object) to do that. It's nothing fancy, but it does the job and has saved me a couple of times already :)

```
function listAllProperties(o) {
  var objectToInspect;
  var result = [];

  for(objectToInspect = o; objectToInspect !== null;
          objectToInspect = Object.getPrototypeOf(objectToInspect)) {
        result = result.concat(
          Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objectToInspect)
        );
    }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted isn't live any more.

I'm guessing the below links are more relevant now for others looking into this. I animated a series of blendShapes, and these links were useful. Basically cycling through the weights of each blendShape.

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/scenemodule.blendshapesmesh

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/scenemodule.blendshape